# why passport deserializeUser not called

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local, express-session

```
// used to serialize the user for the session

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("serializuser called " ,user);
        done(null, user.username);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log("de serializuser called ",user);
        done(null, user);
    });
```

why passport does not create a session  when I use **user.username** in serialize function but session works fine when I use **user** object

Comment: ************************************************
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Mon Aug 07 2017 14:48:49 GMT+0530 (IST),
     originalMaxAge: 59999,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true },
  passport: { user: 'admin' } }

***************************************************************

Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Mon Aug 07 2017 14:50:28 GMT+0530 (IST),
     originalMaxAge: 59997,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true },
  passport: { user: { username: 'admin', admin: '1', status: true } } }

*****************************

Comment: Please clarify the question. Add more code or description so that we can understand your problem.